# Controlling PC cursor with joystick in java

Tags: java, xbox360

I have a program that is supposed to allow the use of my computer with a xbox 360 remote. The direction of the joystick is in degrees, where directly up is 0 degrees, right is 90 degrees, down is 180 degrees, and left is 270 degrees. And of course there is everything between those values also. I'm a bit confused with the math of how to turn these angle measures into usable x and y coordinates for the mouse. I already know how to calculate the mouse speed using the joystick magnitude which is a double value of 0 to 1.

My question is how would I use the degree value of the joystick to move the cursor?

```
public void main()
    {
        //Wait for a controller to connect before program continues
        xc = new XboxController();
        while (!xc.isConnected())
        {
            System.out.println("Waiting for controller...");
            xc = new XboxController();
        }
        System.out.println("Connected!");

        try
        {
            //This robot will be used to change the mouse coordinates and perform clicks
            robot = new Robot();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Get the screen dimensions
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        screenWidth = (int)screenSize.getWidth();
        screenHeight = (int)screenSize.getHeight();

        xc.addXboxControllerListener(new XboxControllerAdapter()
        {
            //Is called every time the leftThumbStick's direction is changed
            //The direction value is in degrees
            public void leftThumbDirection(double direction)
            {
                System.out.println("Left degree direction: "+(int)direction);
                //Need to calculate the new coordinates of the mouse based on the joystick
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: If you would like to ask a Java question, please provide some java code

Comment: What is the question ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [robot.mouseMove()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#mouseMove(int,%20int))

Comment: That is how I set the coordinates of the mouse. I cant figure how to calculate the coordinates based on the joystick.